# How to render CSS only according to screen size of end user?

Tags: css

İn a classic application When the end user enters the page, we try to give all the CSS belonging to the page. However, end user only interested in with visible part of the page. We load CSS components belongs to visible page size,but non-visible part as well.

How i can make it possible load CSS components when needed? 
For example: When end user scrolls down,then load required CSS components.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your purpose here? It would seem more logical to only load images that are shown on the screen and there are many libraries to do this. Css-files are generally so small compared to the images that the amount badwith you would gain from this is not worth it. Of course this can be done with javascript, but the amount of javascript needed for this could surpass the amount of badwith saved.

Comment: First of all  thanks for response.

I want to load CSS only user needed. I don't want browser loads CSS components which is not needed.Only loads content's css which  visible for user.

Comment: If you want to load your css at start, but only apply some css rules when needed, then you can use media queries. If you want css resources to get imported and loaded when needed, A lazy-loading of css would require you to use javascript. And I'm pretty sure that would drastically decrease the overall performance.

Comment: Appreciate your response. you fulfilled my question and i got what i need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the `@media` query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

This way you can do this with all screen sizes

You can read more about this at: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp